# Why does python show up error that name tk is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, syntax

I was trying to built a small window with tkitner and it showed up this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\education\python\example .py", line 3, in <module>
    master = TK()
NameError: name 'TK' is not defined
```

```
from tkinter import *

master = TK()
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not `TK()`, its `Tk()` (Small k).
Also, using `from ... import *` is [dangerous and should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Comment: very thanks i have been fighting with this for 3 days an why from ... import * is dangerous

Comment: @ahamedsha You can check the link which has an answer with the most important reasons for why this is dangerous but in a short answer - You don't know what you've just imported into your namespace